# Direct analytic proof of positive definiteness of stable characteristic functions

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, probability-distributions, fourier-analysis

Is there a **direct analytic** proof that the function
$$
f ( t ) =
\exp\left(-|t|^\alpha \big[ \lambda + i \theta \operatorname{sign} ( t ) \big]\right),
\qquad
\lambda > 0, \quad
|\theta| < \lambda \left| \tan\left(\frac{\pi \alpha}{2}\right) \right|
$$
(characteristic function of stable distribution) is positive definite?

By *direct* and *analytic* I mean one that doesn't use the Lèvy construction or any other probabilistic arguments.

To give an example of the kind of proof I'd like to find, consider the case $\lambda = 1$ and $\theta = 0$. Then by Bernstein's theorem there exists a finite measure on $(0, \infty)$ such that
$$
\exp(-|t|^\alpha) = \int_0^\infty e^{-ut^2} \mathop{d\mu_{\alpha} ( u )}.
$$
Taking Fourier transform of both sides we find that
$$
\mathcal{F} \left[ \exp ( -|t|^\alpha ) \right] ( \xi )
=
\sqrt{\pi} \int_0^\infty u^{-1/2} e^{-\xi^2/4u} \mathop{d\mu_{\alpha} ( u )} > 0. 
$$